# .animate return back to original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jquery-animate

Currently I'm using this code for animating back to original state

```
this.stop().animate(animateVal1, animateMs).delay(duration).animate(animateVal2, animateMs, function() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

Is that possible to return back original state without fading to second color `animateVal2`? (I mean after animating to first color I want to remove `style` attribute with animation.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your question:

You have a element `X`, which is in state `A` (due to some applied classes from CSS Rules).

You want to animate it to state `B`, using `jquery.animate()`, but you want to return it to the original state `A`. But you do not have a Javascript object containing all the properties of `A` at the time the animate function can execute.

For this, I recommend you use jQuery UI's [switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/) function.

```
this.stop().switchClass('classB', animateMs).delay(duration).switchClass('originalClass', animateMs);
```